# understanding for loops and multidimensional arrays

Tags: python, for-loop, multidimensional-array, python-3.5

as a hobby project I'm trying to make a grid of public available route listeners on the internet, for this, i'm logging into all of them and asking them them who they know and who is directly connected to them. which works fine, now i'm trying to pair them.

the math is pretty simple, if the last octet in the IP address is an even number, it's partner must be the next odd number and vice versa (some exceptions but i do those manually)

Now if you run the script here, you won't get any results, I did this on purpose to illustrate a problem i'm not sure how i reverse-problem-solve on.

Run this and i will get no errors, but if I add another element into the list

```
['ROUTER5124-A', '100.127.126.16', 'te0/0/24']
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zac.py", line 38, in <module>
    linknetsloop.remove(sublist)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

if I print out what inside linknetsloop.remove(sublist) and
            linknetsloop.remove(items) It want's to delete the extra element i added, twice in fact. which is weird since it's partner .17 is not even there. I think the error is me looping through the list wrong, but I can't find my error after a few hours of searching.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5

import re
import ipaddress

linknets = [
['ROUTER1190-A', '100.127.126.81', 'te0/0/2'] ,
['ROUTER1190-A', '100.127.126.83', 'te0/0/3'] ,
['ROUTER1323-A', '100.127.126.125', 'te0/0/24'] ,
['ROUTER1323-A', '100.127.126.97', 'te0/0/25'] ,
['ROUTER1242-B', '100.127.126.173', 'te0/0/25'] ,
['ROUTER1190-B', '100.127.126.55', 'te0/0/24'] ,
['ROUTER1190-B', '100.127.126.57', 'te0/0/25'] ,
['ROUTER1190-C', '100.127.126.171', 'te0/0/24'] ,
['ROUTER1190-C', '100.127.126.59', 'te0/0/25'] ,
['ROUTER5345-A', '100.127.126.25', 'te1/0/12'] ,
['ROUTER5345-A', '100.127.126.47', 'te2/0/12'] ,
['ROUTER1610-A', '100.127.126.69', 'te0/0/24'] ,
['ROUTERP-1242', '100.127.126.85', 'eth1/1/3'] ,
['ROUTERP-1242', '100.127.126.63', 'eth1/1/4'] ,
['ROUTERP-1242', '100.127.126.104', 'eth1/2/1'] ,
]

linknetsloop = linknets
linknets_complete = []

for sublist in linknets:
    search = 0
    lastoctet = re.match('.*?([0-9]+)$', sublist[1]).group(1)
    if int(lastoctet)%2==0: #Last octet is even
        search = ipaddress.IPv4Address(sublist[1]) + 1
    else:
        search = ipaddress.IPv4Address(sublist[1]) - 1
    for items in linknets:
        if str(search) in items[1]:
            print(sublist)
            linknetsloop.remove(sublist)
            linknetsloop.remove(items)
```

any pointers will be gladly appreciated

Comment: Please post post your desired output from `linknets`

Comment: I expect the output from linknets to be the same as when i start the script, the issue is when I add another random list that the script fails.

Comment: What is the output from the linknets?

Comment: This really should be a simple debugging issue for you, but you deleted the same thing twice. The second time you delete it, it is not there, and it raises an error saying so. Also, I don't know why you add 1 to the ipaddress, changing it. Also, you are matching '100.127.126.17' to '100.127.126.173' and '100.127.126.171' because of "in"

Comment: It probably should,

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you wanted to **copy** the content of `linknets`:

```
linknetsloop = list(linknets)
```

Your original code does not copy the list, but merely creates alias to the same list. And then you are iterating on it, and changing its content while iterating, which will lead to unexpected results.

Then, you do a double loop on `linknests` and double deletion:

```
for sublist in linknets:
    ....
    for items in linknets:
        if <condition>:
            linknetsloop.remove(sublist)
            linknetsloop.remove(items)
```

This will raise `ValueError` exception when `sublist==items` and the item with that value exist only once. So you have to consider this situation.

Also, probably you have a bug in :

```
  if str(search) in items[1]:
```

You are not **comparing** strings, but **matching** it. So if your `search` is '10.127.126.16' it will match to '210.127.126.168', for example.

Comment: It's from removing sublist inside the loop, up to len(linknets) times.